# macbook pro to external monitor 1920px via hdmi?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, resolution

I just got macbook pro 13inch retina and the default resolution is 1280px width, and maximum is 1600px.

If I connect this laptop to an external monitor via HDMI which has 1920px resolution, will the resolution really be 1920, since laptop's max is 1600?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will get 1920x1080 resolution.

The native resolution of a 13" Retina Macbook Pro is actually much higher. From Apples website:

> Retina display: 13.3-inch (diagonal) LED-backlit display with IPS technology; 2560-by-1600 resolution at 227 pixels per inch with support for millions of colors
>
> Native resolution: 2560 by 1600 pixels (Retina); scaled resolutions: 1680 by 1050, 1440 by 900, and 1024 by 640 pixels

The 13" retina MBP can also handle 1080P and higher resolutions through HDMI:

> HDMI video output
>
> Support for 1080p resolution at up to 60Hz
>
> Support for 3840-by-2160 resolution at 30Hz
>
> Support for 4096-by-2160 resolution at 24Hz

http://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs-retina/

Comment: TL;DR - Yes....

Comment: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I don't argue against that @Yanzzee, just pointing out it would have made the post much clearer to start by saying "Yes, ..." and then go into the full explanation.

Comment: OK, answer edited.

Comment: Great, now I am comfortable upvoting it ;)